# What does the 2nd argument in strtoul() function do?

Tags: c, hex, strtoul

According to [this document](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/strtoul.html),

> The second argument (char **endptr) seems to be a waste of space! If
>   it is set to NULL, STRTOL seems to work its way down the string until
>   it finds an invalid character and then stops. All valid chars read are
>   then converted if the string starts with an invalid character the
>   function returns ZERO (0).

It means that the following code should detect `2` as the hex number:

```
int main()
{
    char * string = "p1pp2ppp";

    unsigned integer = strtoul(string, NULL, 16);

    printf("%u", integer);

    return 0;
}
```

but, it is returning zero.

Why?

Comment: The function will attempt to parse the string from the *beginning*. And since the first character is not a hexadecimal digit it will fail immediately (as [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul)).

Comment: I'd recommend to read the "official" documentation as well: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4

Comment: well, that document is wrong. If endptr is passed, its is set to pointer of the first character after le last digit parsed and often that's very useful

Comment: As for the `endptr` argument, it's dereferenced to give back a pointer to the first unparsed character in the string.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, *it's dereferenced to give back a pointer to the first unparsed character in the string.* - what is its usefulness?

Comment: There could be many use-cases. Most often it's used to check if *all* of the string was parsed (for example `"123"` where the end pointer would be to the terminator) or only the beginning part (like for `"123xyz"` where the end pointer would be to the `'x'`).

Comment: The quality of the reference material can be determined from its use of the phrase "seems to". It means the author really doesn't have a clue.

Comment: With `char *p; int i = strtoul("24-3", &p, 10);` `i` will be `24`, `p` will point to `"-3"`.

Comment: That document looks like someone's personal notebook (and HTML practice). It hasn't been updated sice 1998, and is frequently very, very wrong or obsolete.

Comment: Learning C: Rule 1 -> read the documentation. Rule 2 -> don't use crappy documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page says the following about the second argument:

> If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first
>   invalid    character in *endptr.  If there were no digits at all,
>   strtol()  stores    the  original value of nptr in *endptr (and
>   returns 0).  In particular,    if *nptr is not '\0' but **endptr is
>   '\0' on return, the entire  string    is valid.

For example:

```
char str[] = "123xyz45";
char *p;
long x = strtol(str, &p, 10);
printf("x=%ld\n", x);
printf("p - str = %d\n", p - str);
printf("*p = %c\n", *p);
printf("p (as string) = %s\n", p);
```

Output:

```
x=123
p - str = 3
*p = x
p (as string) = xyz45
```

We can see that when `strtol` returns `p` points to the first character in `str` that cannot be converted.  This can be used to parse through the string a bit at a time, or to see if the entire string can be converted or if there are some extra characters.

In the case of your example, the first character in `string`, namely "p" is not a base 10 digit so nothing gets converted and the function returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

> Why?

It's returning `0` because `"p..."` does not follow any rules about integer representation. *The 2nd argument is not relevant for your question.*

Answer (score 0):

The `char **endptr` argument in all the `strto*` functions is intended to receive the address of the first character that *isn’t* part of a valid integer (decimal, hex, or octal) or floating point number.  Far from useless, it’s handy for checking invalid input.  For example, if I meant to type in `1234` but fat-fingered something like `12w4`, `strtoul` will return `12` and set the endptr argument to point to `w`.

Basically, if the character `endptr` points to isn’t whitespace or `0`, then the input should most likely be rejected.